# C++ dynamic_cast runtime-error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, runtime-error, dynamic-cast

I have written a small application using dynamic_cast to determine whether it is form the base class or the child class and invokes the function according to it. But when ever child class 
runs, it displays it function twice and no sure why it does that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the base class" << endl;
    }
    virtual void say(){
        cout << "Base class says hi" << endl;
    }
};

class Child:public Base{
public:
    void setting(){
        cout << "Hello, I am a function from the child class" << endl;
    }
    void say(){
        cout << "Child class says hi" << endl;
    }
};

void Ready(Base* input){
    Base* bp = dynamic_cast<Base*>(input);
    if(bp){
        bp->setting();
        bp->say();
    }
    Child* cp = dynamic_cast<Child*>(input);
    if(cp){
        cp->say();
        cp->setting();
    }
}

int main(){
    Base b;
    Child c;
    Ready(&b);
    cout << endl;
    Ready(&c); //runs twice for some reason
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a pointer to `Child` to the `Ready` function, both `dynamic_casts` succeed. `Child` is both a `Base` and a `Child`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
struct Foo
{
  virtual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar : Foo {};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Bar b;
  std::cout << dynamic_cast<Foo*>(&b) << std::endl;
  std::cout << dynamic_cast<Bar*>(&b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So what should have been do prevent something like this from happening. Any changes to the code?

Comment: @user3264250 I think you havent grasped inheritance yet. The point about inheritance is, that you dont care about the concrete type of an object but just about the interface it provides. Just do `input->setting();` without any casts.

Comment: @user3264250 Your code doesn't make much sense to me, so I don't know what would "fix" your "problem". If you describe the desired outcome, I can suggest a solution.